# Discord.py bot, random image poster

Tags: python, discord

So I'm trying to make a bot that posts a random image from a local directory. I can't seem to figure out what to do. I've spent some time looking at some methods online but most of them have to do with embedded links.

```
#Version 1.1.0

import os
import random
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext    import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot

#Release#
TOKEN = 'token#'

#WIP#
#TOKEN = 'TOKEN#'

default_emojis = [
    ""
]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!croc')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("CrocBOT | Version 1.1.0")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('A user has entered a command.')
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('version'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('CrocBOT | Version 1.1.0')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if "croc" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "aligator" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "caiman" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "gharial" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "alligator" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")  
    elif "liopleurodon" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "nile" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "sagan" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "krokodil" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "sobek" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")  
    elif "spin" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "roll" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "крокодил" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")  
    elif "gavialis" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    elif "" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")  
    elif ":crocodile:" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")



#with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as f:
#    picture = discord.File(f)
#    await channel.send(channel, picture)

#@bot.command()
#async def pic():   
#    fp = random.choice(os.listdir("D:\Discord_BOTs\BOT\CrocBOT\crocs"))
#        await bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "D:\Discord_BOTs\BOT\CrocBOT\crocs{}".png(fp))

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I tried a few things here but changed them to notes since they seem to not work at all. Plus, I'm looking to post images from a local directory.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

Check this url [How to Make a Discord Bot in Python](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/) !

Comment: I already have a bot all setup, just not sure what how to implement this specific feature.